# How to query data by using children attribute?

Tags: mongoose

I have following code:

```
Model.Class.find().populate({
    path: 'student',
    select: '-_id grade',
}).where("student.grade").equals("80").exec(function (err, result) {
    log.info(result);
});
```

It will give me empty array.

How to query data by using children attribute? Is there something wrong inside my code?

Answer (score 0):

Include directly your `where` inside the `populate` like:

```
Story
.find(...)
.populate({
  path: 'fans',
  match: { age: { $gte: 21 }},
  select: 'name -_id',
  options: { limit: 5 }
})
.exec()
```

[Mongoose Documentation Part "Query conditions and other options"](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html)